# Как передать нужный параметр 'meta_query' из WP_Query в $_POST?

Tags: wordpress, ajax

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться. 
Использую для реализации кнопки подгрузки постов по клику этот плагин: https://wordpress.org/plugins/infinite-scroll-and-ajax-load-more/

Проблем с его работой не было, пока для вывода постов использовался стандартный метод, который предлагает wordpress в archive.php:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : 
        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();
```

Но в новом разделе возникла необходимость использовать параметр meta_query и WP_Query соответственно для разделения постов на прошедшие и предстоящие по date-полю AFC:

```
$compare = ( $_GET['type'] === 'past' ) ? '<' : '>=';
$today   = date( 'Ymd' );
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'training',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'event_time_event_day',
            'value'   => $today,
            'compare' => $compare,
            'type'    => 'DATE'
        )
    ),
    'meta_key'       => 'event_time_event_day',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => '5',
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Плагин при нажатии на кнопку "показать ещё" передаёт параметры цикла:

```
wp_localize_script( 'bliss_loadmore', 'bliss_loadmore_params', array(
            'ajaxurl'        => site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            'posts'          => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars )
            ...................

        ) );
```

Но в query_vars содержится, как мне видится (не сильно шарю в wp) параметры, которые используются при стандартном выводе постов, о котором я писал в начале:
(сорри, что в одну строку)

```
 [query] => {"post_type":"training","error":"","m":"","p":0,"post_parent":"","subpost":"","subpost_id":"","attachment":"","attachment_id":0,"name":"","pagename":"","page_id":0,"second":"","minute":"","hour":"","day":0,"monthnum":0,"year":0,"w":0,"category_name":"","tag":"","cat":"","tag_id":"","author":"","author_name":"","feed":"","tb":"","paged":0,"meta_key":"","meta_value":"","preview":"","s":"","sentence":"","title":"","fields":"","menu_order":"","embed":"","category__in":[],"category__not_in":[],"category__and":[],"post__in":[],"post__not_in":[],"post_name__in":[],"tag__in":[],"tag__not_in":[],"tag__and":[],"tag_slug__in":[],"tag_slug__and":[],"post_parent__in":[],"post_parent__not_in":[],"author__in":[],"author__not_in":[],"posts_per_page":5,"ignore_sticky_posts":false,"suppress_filters":false,"cache_results":true,"update_post_term_cache":true,"lazy_load_term_meta":true,"update_post_meta_cache":true,"nopaging":false,"comments_per_page":"50","no_found_rows":false,"order":"DESC"}
```

Как видно, параметра 'meta_query' тут нет. Если вывести **$wp_query**, можно найти следующее:

```
"tax_query":{"meta_query":{"queries":[],"relation":null,"meta_table":null,"meta_id_column":null,"primary_table":null,"primary_id_column":null}...
```

Из-за этого при нажатии на "показать ещё" выводятся как прошедшие, так и предстоящие мероприятия в обоих разделах (при обоих get-запросах). 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне передать нужный параметр?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, проблема решилась добавлением

```
wp_add_inline_script('bliss_loadmore', "
    bliss_loadmore_params.posts = '".json_encode($args)."';
", 'before');
```

после объявления 
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );